# Destroying/removing a static text in c++ win32

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I am using win32 API in c++ and I have a static piece of text. How would I delete the static text when the user presses a button? I can't figure out to do that.

Comment: Impossible to answer accurately without knowing how the static text is created and/or hosted and/or rendered by whatever context in which it appears. My crystal ball tells me the combination of [`GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) and [`DestroyWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow) will do what you want, but that's a pure guess based off an inadequate and incomplete description of the running environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the window handle `hwnd` of the `STATIC` control, you can delete it via `DestroyWindow(hwnd)` or simply make it not be visible with `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE)`.

Comment: Or simply clear its text with `SetWindowText()`/`WM_SETTEXT`